# Setting up infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to set up infinite scroll for days now on my site.
Finally i found a plugin that almost works - [jetpack](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/).

**PROBLEM**: When you scroll down, freshly loaded posts are put on top of the displayed ones.

SOLVED...solution see answer

How do we solve this?

**SOLUTION SUGGESTION?** Maybe it has to do with the fact that my theme uses java-masonry for the grid display and I found [this tutorial page](http://wptheming.com/2013/04/jetpack-infinite-scroll-masonry/) providing code snippets to deal with that.

Maybe I enqueued them wrong?

*I added this in the bottom of my functions.php to enqueue the script and configure jetpack*

```html
   // Jetpack infinite js addon

wp_register_script('ininite-addon', (get_template_directory_uri()."/js/infinite-addon.js"),'infinite-addon',false,true);
   
wp_enqueue_script('infinite-addon');


   // Jetpack infinite scroll

add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container' => 'post-area',
    'footer' => 'footer',
    'wrapper'        => false,
    'posts_per_page' => '7',
) );
```

*and this is the file I created called infinite-addon.js according to the tutorial mentioned above:*

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
     infinite_count = 0;
     // Triggers re-layout on infinite scroll
     $( document.body ).on( 'post-load', function () {
 infinite_count = infinite_count + 1;
 var $container = $('#content');
 var $selector = $('#infinite-view-' + infinite_count);
 var $elements = $selector.find('.hentry');
 $elements.hide();
 $container.masonry( 'appended', $elements, true );
 $elements.fadeIn();
     });
});
```

Thank you SO MUCH for any help !!! And let me know if you need more of my code!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
I found a file called funtions.js in my theme's /js/ directory which contained the following code, obviously for making masonry work:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post-area').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post',
    // options...
  isAnimated: true,
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  }
 
  });
});
```

I just deleted this and replaced it with the snippet above, and now it works like magic!